# CSS: vertical-align on img and list

Tags: html, css

I've build a navigation and I wanted the img and the list (`ul`,`li`) centered on the same line (`vertical-align:middle;`) but the list is above the img. So my question is, how I can get both centered on the same line?

HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href=""><img src=""></img></a>
</div>

<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=""></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

CSS:

#logo, #main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I appreciate every comment and help!

Comment: are you using boostrap?

Comment: No I'm doing it by my own

Comment: oky , so i suggest you use table. so its better way to align same line both.,., u can make both in individual <td> tag. so its its better way if u r not using boostrap.

Comment: that is the worst suggestion ever to use a table for a navigation, just give me a minute and I'll show you. There are a couple of errors with your html/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, you are aligning the list items, while you would want to align `<nav>`.

Comment: I'm almost finished with my site and I couldnt figure that out by my own! Thank you it worked!

Comment: @This.Sven there is a thing with your html/css there, like you don't have to `float: left;` a `display: inline-block;` element. I automatically does that. Also floating the `li` u should have a `clearfix` class on the `ul`.  Just some hints ;)